# Azure PowerShell - Restart-AzWebApp : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-automation

I try to use the following content to restart my webapp-service in Azure.
And I deploy this script in Azure Automation Runbook.

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity
Set-AzContext -Tenant "<secret-uuid>"
Write-Output "Start"
Restart-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "testconfogproxy_group" -Name "testconfogproxy"
Write-Output "Finished"
```

But I got an error message `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` after it executed the `Restart-AzWebApp`.

I don't know why and I also don't know how can I solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object` this issue related to the authentication method you are using to connect to your Azure account.

[image]

You can make use of below modified script to restart the webapp service in Azure in Azure Automation Runbook

```c
$Appid = "your-application-id"
$PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "your-clinet-secret" -AsPlainText -Force
$tenant = "<your-tenant-id>"
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $Appid,$PWord
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $tenant -ServicePrincipal -Subscription "<Your-subscription-id>"
Write-Output "Start"
Restart-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "Venkat" -Name "webappv1"
Write-Output "Finished"
```

Make sure to add `contributor` role for App at the subscription level

***Output***:

```
Environments                                                                                                            
------------                                                                                                            
{[AzureChinaCloud, AzureChinaCloud], [AzureCloud, AzureCloud], [AzureGermanCloud, AzureGermanCloud], [AzureUSGovernme...
Start

GitRemoteName               : 
GitRemoteUri                : 
GitRemoteUsername           : 
GitRemotePassword           : 
AzureStorageAccounts        : 
AzureStoragePath            : {}
State                       : Stopped
HostNames                   : {webappv1.azurewebsites.net}
RepositorySiteName          : webappv1
................
............
```

[image]